# javascript: change property of a specific table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html table:

```
<table class="table-all"> 
<tbody>
      <tr>
           <td>BISFENOLO</td>
           <td>Bisfenolo-AF 10/10</td>
           <td class="right">€ 30,79</td>
           <td class="right">$ 43,00</td>
           <td class="right">1.000,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>BISFENOLO</td>
           <td>BPAF-ALLO 1/11</td>
           <td class="right">€ 46,76</td>
           <td class="right">$ 64,00</td>
           <td class="right">1.000,00</td>
      </tr><tr>
           <td>TOTAL</td>
           <td></td>
           <td class="right">€ 698,72</td>
           <td class="right">$ 97,13</td>
           <td class="right">17,00</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would change the background and the font of row(s) that contains "TOTAL" cell. Any Idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is preventing you from doing that? What *do* you know? If you don't know any JavaScript, then you need to read a basic tutorial.

Comment: I asked because I didn't know how do it. Yes, I have to study more jquery but at the same time i needed to solve that problem. Live long and prosper

Comment: Well, I don't know what you know and what you don't know. It's good to provide information on precisely where you're stuck. If you control the HTML being sent, then what you ought to do is put a class on the targeted elements. The solutions provided below should be considered a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the actual total text and set the parent row colour:

```
$("td:contains('TOTAL')").parent().css('background-color','#d0d0d0')
```

Answer (score 3):

Select all rows, filter to rows that have a td that contains the text "TOTAL", then add your class.

```
$('table.table-all tr').has('td:contains("TOTAL")').addClass("totalRow");
```

Comment: @VisioN I was unsure, is :contains() a css3 selector? and :has()?

Comment: :has() isn't a css3 selector, therefore it is faster to split it off into a second method. However it's just a pointless micro-optimization.

Comment: @KevinB: Neither are. They're inventions of Sizzle. Your way is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is - not using jQuery!

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[2];
tr.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```